# can't able to retrieve the updated value of v in if else statement

Tags: javascript

```
function toUSD(unit) {
  console.log(value1);
  var v = 0;
  try {
    if (unit == 'RUPEE') {
      v = value1 / 76;
    } else if (unit == 'BITCOIN') {
      v = value1 * 9470;
    } else if (unit == 'EUR') {
      v = value1 / 85.26;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('error');
  }

  console.log(v);
  return v;
}
```

Not able to get the updated values from the if-else statement. the value of v in the code is not updated outside the if-else statement.how can I modify this code to make it work.

Comment: Where do you get `value1` from?

Comment: There's no reason why `v` shouldn't be available after the `if/else` statements.

Comment: it will be retrieved from HTML form

Comment: Mabye none of the if statements are being triggered

Comment: **Use your JavaScript debugger**.

Comment: make sure the value1 is a number.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Add `console.log(unit)`, maybe it's not one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine provided there is a `value1` and you pass in values that match the conditions:

```js
var value1 = 3.14 // Added to complete the code

function toUSD(unit) {
  //console.log(value1);
  var v = 0;
  try {
    if (unit == 'RUPEE') {
      v = value1 / 76;
    } else if (unit == 'BITCOIN') {
      v = value1 * 9470;
    } else if (unit == 'EUR') {
      v = value1 / 85.26;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('error');
  }

  console.log(v);
  return v;
}

toUSD("RUPEE");
toUSD("BITCOIN");
toUSD("EUR");
toUSD("xyz");
```